# How to detect if any video is being played now?

Tags: c#, c, vbscript, autoit, autohotkey

How to detect if any video is being played now using [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey), [autoit](/questions/tagged/autoit), [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), or [c](/questions/tagged/c)?

Video could be being played/streamed in any local player, web based player, or html5 player. We do not know the name of player also player may not be in the full screen.

PS. Detecting CPU load may not give the correct result always, so it is not acceptable.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as possible to be remotely accurate.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My guess is this is impossible to do without guesswork involved. (Checking for known video file extensions in open file handles / HTTP connections and then seeing if processes that access video files have high-ish CPU load.)

Comment: What do you mean "any video being played now"? Where? Anywhere on the internet? This question is impossible to answer. -1.

Comment: @TimS. I want my script runs only if there is no any video played/streamed so I have to detect it.

Comment: @EitanT I meant it is played on my pc but without knowing source of video/stream.

Comment: @ide What OS? What type of video? Does an animated GIF count as a video? Do you have a list of known application playing the media that you want to monitor, or does your question regard _any_ video player? If I write my own video player that plays out my own video format, do you expect it to be detected? Do you see where I'm getting at?

Comment: @EitanT Windows 7 and any type of video including streams without GIF. I got it but I cannot monitor Chrome because just opened a YouTube video in html5 and there is no clue in the command line of related Chrome process about it plays a video.

Comment: @EitanT Probably your player should tell to the windows that it is playing a video now so I think answer of my question will be as simple as like that check this windows variable.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a small bit of work on this back in the day. There is a WIN32API (old school) that gets/sets whether or not to disable the screensaver (in user32.dll, GetScreenSaverActive(), SetScreenSaverActive - see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17067/Controlling-The-Screen-Saver-With-C). This is the most likely flag to be set when a video is playing but it not 100% reliable as not every player will implement it. It WILL work for most browser videos, whether played through plugin, natively, or via DirectX. This also works for most (all?) external players such as vlc, windvd, etc.

But.

There is no sure-fire, 100% way of determining a video playing. You cannot;
 1. Check for sound playing as the user may be using iTunes and not all videos have sound
 2. Check for full screen (usually the better option) as the video may be playing in a browser
 3. Check cpu/gpu load as it's not reliable and you have no other way to determine
 4. Be absolutely sure that the player hasn't cleared/reset the win32 flag when minimized

Another option would be to try and collate a list of possile executable names for all known players (doable but time consuming to find data, espesially on older versions), and check to see if they're running. This isn't 100% reliable either as a plugin by be preloaded but a browser but not actually playing a video at that moment in time.

In short, there's no 100% way that I know of but several ways that'll get you 90-95% there. That is the purpose of knowing if there's a video playing? Perhaps there's an easier way to find what you're looking for...

Comment: This only works if the screensaver is enabled.

Comment: @Bonner웃, true. This boils back to my point that there isn't a 100% sure way of doing it